# Assignment Within the Check of a While Loop

Tags: c++, while-loop, io

I was trying out the following basic summation program using while loops:

```
#include <iostream>
using std::cin;
using std::cout;


int main(){

int userIn;
int runningSum =0;

while((std::cin >> userIn) != 0){
   if(userIn == 0) std::cout << "Should never execute";
   runningSum += userIn;
}
return runningSum;
}
```

I'm having some trouble understanding why the while loop executes even if the user enters 0.

Comment: Reading references of functions/operators is better way to learn c++ than just wild guessing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`(std::cin >> userIn)` will be `!= 0` if the input succeeded, not if the input was `0`.

To check both, you can do `while ( (std::cint >> userIn) && userIn )`. This will first make sure that the input succeeded and then that the number is actually non-zero.

Answer (score 0):

It would be beneficial for you to get used to reference pages like
http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/istream/istream/operator%3E%3E/

It describes the return value of the operator>>() function, which is the istream (cin) objects itself. This means that

`while((std::cin >> userIn) != 0)`

will not do what you expect it to do, and the loop will actually never be broken.

What you're actually looking for is something along the lines of

```
std::cin >> userIn;
do {
   if(userIn == 0) std::cout << "Should never execute";
   runningSum += userIn;
   std::cin >> userIn;
} while (userIn != -1);
```